# get the input from a script and echo it to another file

Tags: bash, scripting

I have a python script that create some files and it ask me to enter a password this script is called from bash script
is their any way to get the entered password and echo it to text file

Comment: You tried anything?

Comment: no i don't know how to do this

Comment: If it's `python` that's asking for the password, you could just have it write it to a file for you, right?

Comment: the paython script take the username from bash script as an argument and the ask me to enter password
okay 

bash script contains argument called client that i enter as input while running bash then i call the python script (wish i got from internet not mine )

the bashfrom script is like this
echo $CLIENT > login.txt

user-add.py $CLIENT

then python asks me to enter password 

i want a way to read this password and add it to the login.txt in order that the login has the username which is get form shell script and pass which is entered after running the python script

Comment: @KhalidAboElMaGd I'd recommend having python write both the username and password to login.txt once it has them both, though are you really sure you want to put the password in clear text in a file?

Comment: yes its okay to put it clearly in text file ...
this is the python script could you tell me how to put the user and password to the text file
http://pastebin.com/yhfP3sjT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the python script has both the username and password, it could write them into the file for you.

```
with open('/etc/openvpn/clients/%s/login.txt' % username, 'w') as login_log:
    login_log.write('%s\n%s\n' % (username, password))
```

which will open `login.txt`, overwriting the file if one already existed, and write the username on the first line then the password on the second line

Comment: this is the script so can you modify it

http://pastebin.com/yhfP3sjT

Comment: So rename the variables above to `username` and `password` and put those lines either before or after you hash the password, depending on which you want in the file

Comment: i need the login.text to be in this place
/etc/openvpn/clients/$CLIENT/login.txt
where is the $CLIENT is the username
the file will be created by the python
and i need the password not hashed so could you please tell me what to put and where cause i know nothing about python..thanks in advance

Comment: @KhalidAboElMaGd see my edit to open the file in that location, and to have it log the clear text password I'd put it just before the line where you hash the password

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "password please..."
read pass
echo $pass > file.txt
```

Comment: Probably better would be `read -s -p "password please..." pass`, at least with bash, so the password doesn't get displayed again in the terminal

Comment: the paython script take the username from bash script as an argument and the ask me to enter password
okay 

bash script contains argument called client that i enter as input while running bash then i call the python script (wish i got from internet not mine )

the bashfrom script is like this
echo $CLIENT > login.txt

user-add.py $CLIENT

then python asks me to enter password 

i want a way to read this password and add it to the login.txt in order that the login has the username which is get form shell script and pass which is entered after running the python script